# how to struct initializer and deque

Tags: c++

So i have..

```
struct Polynomial{
    deque<long> coefs;
    long degree;

    Polynomial(initializer_list<long> co_list);
    Polynomial(deque<long> & co_list);
    Polynomial();
    string poly_to_string();
    Polynomial add(Polynomial rhs);
    Polynomial mult(Polynomial rhs);
    Polynomial mult(long factor);
}
```

For theese methods I have to :

Polynomial(initializer_list cfs ). Initialize the instance using an initializer list of coefficients. 
-order is the highest power goes first, lowest last 
-coefs and degree updated.

Polynomial(deque cfs). Initialize the instance using a vector of coefficients. -order is the highest power goes first, lowest last 
-coefs and degree updated.

Then I do methods to add/multiple/factor the polynomial, which I can do, just not sure what

```
Polynomial(initializer_list<long> co_list);
Polynomial(deque<long> & co_list);
```

are suppose to do / how to start them..

Also, how would i would I start the function to return
    Polynomial.degree
To return a long value?

Comment: These questions are much better answered by taking a class, or reading a book.  stackoverflow.com is not here to teach language basics.

Comment: Each (initializer_list, deque) has begin, end and size you might use to initialize your coefficients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two functions are the constructors for the type.  They tell the compiler how to set up a `Polynomial` object so that it's ready for members to be called.  They're most easily understood like this:

```
struct Polynomial{
    deque<long> coefs;
    long degree;

    Polynomial(initializer_list<long> co_list);
    Polynomial(deque<long> & co_list);
};
Polynomial::Polynomial(initializer_list<long> co_list) 
{
    //at this point, the members are created, but have no values
    //so we assign values to the members
    coefs.assign(co_list.begin(), co_list.end());
    degree = co_list.size();
}  
int main() 
{
    Polynomial mypoly = {3, 4, 5}; 
    //creates a Polynomial variable from an initializer list
    //the compiler runs the constructor function automatically
    //so now it's members are all properly set, and we can run other functions
    mypoly.do_thing();
}
```

However, as shown above, the `Polynomial` constructor constructs the two members, and then executes the function that assigns them values.  We can make this even better by constructing them directly with the intended values:

```
Polynomial::Polynomial(initializer_list<long> co_list) 
    :
    coefs(co_list.begin(), co_list.end()), //constructed directly
    degree(co_list.size())
{
    //they already have the needed values, don't need to do anything more
    //to finalize the construction
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate the explanations for each part so I can will be able to replicate by myself in the future!

Comment: @lpawnu43, please if the answer is so good for you, upvote it or mark it. Your vote is important for people be encouraged to help you again in the future.